# Intermittent iPad app crashing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, exception, orientation

I'm building an article reading app on for iPad using split view controller.
I'm facing a problem of intermittent crashing of app and there is no error in console.
Sometime app is crashed on changing orientation and sometime it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is crashing on change of the orientation then you have to add following method into your controller.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

It will solve your problem

Comment: thanks,its not happening after applying this method app is still crashing.I applied this detail view controller class.                                                       -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: Please add this method in each controller and please check once

Comment: @ Vipul,I have added in all classes but its not working.